Unable to catch Timeout Exception in Python Gracefully
I am having below code:
async with session.get(endpoint, timeout=10) as response:
        if response.status != 200:
            return self.result(endpoint, response.status)  

except aiohttp.ServerTimeoutError:
    settings.log.info(f"Host  {endpoint} is unreachable")
    return self.result(endpoint, -1)        
except TimeoutError:
    json = {"status": "unhealthy"}
    settings.log.info(f"Host  {endpoint} has timed out")
    return self.result(endpoint, -1)
except aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError:
    json = { "status": "unhealthy"}
    settings.log.info(f"Host  {endpoint} has timed out")
    return self.result(endpoint, -1)

I am getting below error:
async with session.get(endpoint, timeout=10) as response:
asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError: 

Whenever i run the code, exception occurs for the endpoint which is not reachable and codes exits ungracefully.
I want to return the unhealthy state, without exiting the code.Please Help!

So catch the asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError exception, and handle it however you want.  What is the difficulty?

It appears to be throwing a asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError and not the regular TimeoutError or aiohttp.ServerTimeoutError (note that TimeoutError is different to asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError in Python 3.10 and earlier).
So you need to catch that as well like this:
...
except asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError:
    json = {"status": "unhealthy"}
    settings.log.info(f"Host  {endpoint} has timed out")
    return self.result(endpoint, -1)

You might also need to import asyncio.excpetions at the top of the file like this:
import asyncio.exceptions

Note that in Python 3.11+, they are the same.
